# Embeding same object in two Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, relationship

I have a user and a clinic model as such:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :phone, inverse_of: :personal_phone
end

class Clinic
  include Mongoid::Docuement
  embeds_many :phones, inverse_of: :clinic_phone
end
```

Now I have a phone class that I want to Embed in either user or the clinic. So When I initialize a phone object I want to have a choice to embed it in either user or clinic.  I tried the following:

```
class Phone
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :personal_phone
  embedded_in :clinic, inverse_of: :clinic_form
end
```

Now when I do save the phone for user it works, but when I try to save a phone for clinic I get the following error:
Mongoid has two different path objects for determining the location of a document in the database, Root and Embedded. This error is raised when an embedded document somehow gets a root path assigned.

Any ideas how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution for this problem.